# Prepopulate NewForm.aspx Lookup DropDownList SharePoint 2013 with Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery

In SP2010 I used the following JavaScript(JS) in a Content Editor on the NewForm.aspx page.  This was used to prepopulate a lookup dropdownlist with a value from the Query String Parameter.  Now that I've converted to SP2013, the JavaScript is failing to locate what appears to be a completely different looking Lookup Dropdown in the HTML.  Is there a quick fix for this code?  Recommendations please!

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">
// This javascript sets the default value of a lookup field identified 
// by <<FIELD DISPLAY NAME>> to the value stored in the querysting variable
// identified by <<QUERYSTRING VARIABLE NAME>>
// Customize this javascript by replacing <<FIELD DISPLAY NAME>> and 
// <<QUERYSTRING VARIABLE NAME>> with appropriate values.
// Then just paste it into NewForm.aspx inside PlaceHolderMain

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fillDefaultValues");

function fillDefaultValues() 
{
//Get's parent URL then substrings to the first querystring value
var qs = parent.location.search.substring(1, parent.location.search.length);
//Separates all values separated with &
var args = qs.split("&");
var vals = new Object();
for (var i=0; i < args.length; i++) 
    {
        var nameVal = args[i].split("=");
        var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+');
        nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ');
        vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
    }  
setLookupFromFieldName("Project ID", vals["ProjectID"]);
}

function setLookupFromFieldName(fieldName, value) 
{
    if (value == undefined) return;
    var theSelect = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("select","Lookup",fieldName);

// if theSelect is null, it means that the target list has more than
// 20 items, and the Lookup is being rendered with an input element

if (theSelect == null) 
    { 
        var theInput = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input","",fieldName);
        ShowDropdown(theInput.id); //this function is provided by SharePoint and shows the drop down being pulled
        var opt=document.getElementById(theInput.opt);
        setSelectedOption(opt, value);
        OptLoseFocus(opt); //this function is provided by SharePoint 
    } 
    else 
    {
        setSelectedOption(theSelect, value);
    }
}

function setSelectedOption(select, value) 
{
    var opts = select.options;
    var l = opts.length;
    if (select == null) return;
    for (var i=0; i < l; i++) 
        {
            if (opts[i].value == value) 
                {
                  select.selectedIndex = i;
                  return true;
                }
        }
    return false;
}

function getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(tagName, identifier, title) 
//Finds returns the drop down list object by locating the tag in HTML
{
    var len = identifier.length;
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++)
        {
            var tempString = tags[i].id;
            if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" || tempString.indexOf(identifier) == tempString.length - len)) 
                {
alert(tags[i].id);
                    return tags[i];
                }
        }
    return null;
}
</script>&#160;</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

After some more analysis, I resolved the code above.  Looks like the conversion from SP2010 to SP2013 changed the value the javascript was looking for in the dropDownList.

var theSelect = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("select",**"Lookup"**,fieldName);

I changed the **Lookup** to **LookupField** and the JavaScript above started working again.